# I cannot verify contract on etherscan

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan

I cannot deploy my contract so I test with simplestorage but I cannot verify it either.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract SimpleStorage {
uint storedData;

function set(uint x) public {
    storedData = x;
}

function get() public view returns (uint) {
    return storedData;
}
}
```

Look at the solidity compiler version and optimize option.
https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=true&version=soljson-v0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.js

And the configuration I used to verify the contract deployed on ropsten.
[image]

Is there anything I am missing?
Thanks